# python how to choose just special elements from df string

Tags: python, pandas

Please, help.
I need to choose just 'yellow', 'green', 'black' or combinatons of these elements, if there are several of them in the string.
df:

```
0 ['blue','green','white','yellow','orange','pink','black']
1 ['green','yellow','orange','pink','pink']
2 ['white','orange','black']
3 ['green','white','yellow','orange']
4 ['green']
```

the result should be like:

```
0 ['green','yellow','black']
1 ['green','yellow']
2 ['black']
3 ['green','yellow']
4 ['green']
```

Comment: Can the input array have for example 'yellow' more than once? If so what should the output be in that case?

Comment: @JoseNuno in my case - no. The string contains this or that color just once.

Comment: Are they stored as list in the dataframe or string?

Comment: @ThePyGuy like string, but I converted them to list through .str.split(",")

Answer (score 1):

Your dataframe `df`:

```
    val
0   ['blue','green','white','yellow','orange','pin...
1   ['green','yellow','orange','pink','pink']
2   ['white','orange','black']
3   ['green','white','yellow','orange']
4   ['green']
```

Try with `apply()` and list comprehension:

```
df['val']=df['val'].apply(lambda x:eval(x))  #use this only when the data inside val is string
```

**Note:** If the above line throw you can error then simply skip it and move to the code below(It means that the data inside val column is of type list)

Finally:

```
df['val']=df['val'].apply(lambda x:[y for y in x if y=='yellow' or y=='green' or y=='black'])
```

OR(use any one code)

```
df['val']=df['val'].apply(lambda x:[y for y in x if y in ['yellow','green','black']])
```

Now If you print `df` you will get:

```
    val
0   [green, yellow, black]
1   [green, yellow]
2   [black]
3   [green, yellow]
4   [green]
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY:

```
import ast
df.val = df.val.apply(
    lambda x: [y for y in ast.literal_eval(x) if y in ['yellow', 'green', 'black']]
)
```